# Possible Risks of Publicizing Personal Stock Portfolio

Tags: investing, trading, portfolio

I have been investing in the stock market on a small-to-medium sized personal account for several years now, and I am considering making my investment history publicly available online.  My question is, are there any reasons (legal, personal, etc.) *not to* publicize my personal investment history?

Some account details:

- Size: around $50,000
- Primarily trade options
- Average about 2-3 trades per month
- Have had moderate success

Comment: What job would such info be beneficial?

Comment: Could be beneficial for any job that involves investing

Comment: How would you prove that you made the investments you claim to have made?

Comment: That's a good question...while I do have official transaction receipts, I suppose it would be on the honor code–just like if someone claimed to have graduated college, they would most likely not need to present a diploma as proof

Comment: If a job that involves investing wanted to see your history they'd ask for it.  Making your actual trades fully public gives you nothing.

Comment: @quid that's possible, but it's also possible that an employer might appreciate the information, even though they might not ask for it.

Comment: I can't fathom a downside, I just don't think there's an upside.  If you want to give this a shot, I don't see how it could be bad for you.

Comment: Legal reasons ... need country tag. Although I can't think of any country have such restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

> I am considering making my investment history publicly available online

What is the benefit you are looking for by doing this? Just to establish that you are a successful investor, so in long run can predict things ... have tons of followers? If so yes. Go ahead. Updates to the portfolio would have to be near real-time than post facto else no one will believe you and it would be useless.

> are there any reasons (legal, personal, etc.) not to publicize my personal investment history

legal, depends on country; I can't think any [check the agreement with your broker / depository] on how much can be displayed. i.e. they may forbid from revealing contract ref / or some other details.

On Personal front, it depends who takes a liking to your stuff.

**Relatives**: They know you are making huge profits and may want to borrow stuff ... or queue up to you requesting to make similar huge profits for them; only to realize when there is loss they blame you ... this can strain relationships.

**Friends**: Although close friends may have a general idea, if you are too successful and it shows; it can have its own set of issues to deal with.

**Colleagues / Manager**: If you are too successful, it may mean you may notionally be earning more than them ... they would start unconsciously monitoring your behaviour ... this guy spends all day in office researching for stocks and doesn't work. That way he knows how to pick good stock ... he is wasting company time. The same happens if you are loosing stock ... a unrelated bad day you are having maybe equated to loss in stocks. Depending on the job / roles, they may move you to different role as the perceived risk of you swindling goes up.
Generally important work doesn't get assigned, as it would be assumed that if you are successful in investing, you may quite soon and start full time into it.

**Identify Theft**: As mentioned by keshlam, to much data one can easily risk identity theft. Realize phone banking to get some routine stuff just asks for basic details [that are available on face book] and few recent debits / credits to the account. This will be easy see the trades you have done. None of us here are expert identity theifs. But the real one have tons of way t

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Although I didn't really mean to ask for risks such as strained relationships with friends and family, these are important things to consider as well.  It also seems like identity theft could be a legitimate problem, so I will definitely look into it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You would be facilitating identity theft. You would be risking people who disagree with your approach thinking you're foolish.

Are you really going to gain enough from this decision to offset the risks? Can't you do the same thing with much less detail or a "fantasy" account?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not really worried about anyone thinking I'm foolish, but I would certainly be worried about the possibility of identity theft.  Could you explain a bit more about how publicizing my investment history could help facilitate identity theft?

Comment: Information can sometimes be leveraged to expose more information, and so on. Account numbers would certainly put you at risk, but it might be possible to recover those if one knows exactly balances plus other data.  Discuss generalities, if you like, but I really don't advocate exposing more than ballpark numbers. Others may be less paranoid, but I stay with "don't challenge Darwin; don't take risks that don't benefit you."

Comment: Agreed. There are tons of way to correlate different data sets.

Comment: If you publisise your results from a spreadsheet showing no actual account details, then the only identity you are revealing is your name. Your name is probably already out there on the internet many times over already.